# Why ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor produce different SDDL when directory inheritance is changed?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, directory

We use SDDL to compare directories permissions.

In most cases, when I use ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor or GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm I get identical results (SDDL).

But when the directory permissions inheritance is changed the pseudo code below will produce different strings (SDDL).

What do I need to do in the Win32 implementation to make it produce same SDDL as the .Net?

Win32 (called from a .Net app):

```
IntPtr pSidOwner = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr pSidGroup = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr pDacl = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr pSacl = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
uint errorReturn = GetNamedSecurityInfo(path, SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT, ACS, out pSidOwner, out pSidGroup, out pDacl, out pSacl, out pSecurityDescriptor);
if (errorReturn != 0)
{
   throw new Win32Exception((int)errorReturn);
}

int len = 0;
IntPtr pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
if (ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(pSecurityDescriptor, 1, si, out pBuffer, out len))
{
    String sddl = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pBuffer);
}
```

.Net 4.5:

```
 FileSystemSecurity fss = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
 String sddl = fss.GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm(ACS);
```

ACS = Owner and DACL

---

[edit]

**The issue was found elsewhere**

I suspected the order but after further investigation found that the issue was a missing flag in the code that make use of the SDDL string.
Apparently I had to use both `DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` and `UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` when calling `SetNamedSecurityInfo` to set DACL. Adding the flag solved the issue.

Thank you Harry for looking into this!

Comment: Provide an example, please.

Comment: I created a folder and removed inheritance (convert into explicit)
C# call sddl=O:S-1-5-21-774854172-2599166104-2634027179-1003D:PAI(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;S-1-5-21-774854172-2599166104-2634027179-1010)
Win32 call  sddl=O:S-1-5-21-774854172-2599166104-2634027179-1003D:PAI(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;S-1-5-21-774854172-2599166104-2634027179-1010)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;AU)

Comment: Looks like `FileSystemSecurity` is reordering the ACEs.  My best guess is that they are being sorted by the associated SID, in the example you provide the SIDs are ascending (S-1-5-11, S-1-5-18, S-1-5-21-...-544, S-1-5-21-...-545, S-1-5-21-...-1010).

Comment: Of course, since this is undocumented, it may depend on the specific version of .NET and/or the operating system.  Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may need to reorder both SDDLs yourself in order to be certain of obtaining consistent results.

Comment: Solved.  
I suspected the order but after further investigation found that the issue was a missing flag in the code that make use of the SDDL string.  
Apparently you need to use both **DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION** and **UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION** when calling **SetNamedSecurityInfo**.  
Adding the flag solved the issue.

Thank you **Harry** for looking into this!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was found elsewhere (please see edit for details)

From what we found  `ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor` and `GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm` produce the same SDDL string (different order in some cases).